# How to reset the indexing in R after deleting rows in csv in python jupyter?

Tags: python, dataframe

I deleted 2nd row in my csv.
Now the index is like [image: this]

so I want my row indexing as 0,1,2
instead of 0,2,3.

Comment: Try opening the csv file in apps like Excel, delete the row, save and import the file again. If you are up to something else, you can edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: To be specific, I delete 2nd row in my dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas.reset_index

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html